# PHP GraphViz Documentation

Tags: php, graphviz

Has anyone used graphviz-php and if so do they know where I can find any documentation regarding its usage/class structure etc?

Please note that this is the graphviz-php not the pear (image_graphviz).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an explanation of the graphviz.php as below.

The GraphViz class allows for the creation of and the work with directed and undirected graphs and their visualization with AT&T's GraphViz tools.

```
  require_once 'Image/GraphViz.php';

  $graph = new Image_GraphViz();

  $graph->addNode(
    'Node1',
    array(
      'URL'   => 'http://link1',
      'label' => 'This is a label',
      'shape' => 'box'
    )
  );

  $graph->addNode(
    'Node2',
    array(
      'URL'      => 'http://link2',
      'fontsize' => '14'
    )
  );

  $graph->addNode(
    'Node3',
    array(
      'URL'      => 'http://link3',
      'fontsize' => '20'
    )
  );

  $graph->addEdge(
    array(
      'Node1' => 'Node2'
    ),
    array(
      'label' => 'Edge Label'
    )
  );

  $graph->addEdge(
     array(
       'Node1' => 'Node2'
     ),
     array(
      'color' => 'red'
   )
  );
  $graph->image();
```

Comment: this link works: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php

Answer (score 3):

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php contains a usage example (updated)

Comment: I saw this one but I installed the php-graphviz rpm is that not different to the pear version?

Comment: I have just checked and it does appear to be different I there is also a php-pear-image-graphviz rpm.

Comment: Name        : graphviz-php                 Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.16.1                            Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 0.6.fc10                      Build Date: Mon 07 Jul 2008 07:22:19 PM BST
Group       : Applications/Multimedia       Source RPM: graphviz-2.16.1-0.6.fc10.src.rpm
Packager    : Fedora Project
URL         : http://www.graphviz.org/
Summary     : PHP extension for graphviz
Description : PHP extension for graphviz.

Comment: this link works http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS, when you install the "graphviz-php" package you get a man page. It's pretty terse, you wouldn't want that to be your only reference, but at least you get something.

```
man 3 gv
```

For what it's worth, there's a very simple example here...

https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/blob/master/tclpkg/gv/demo/modgraph.php