# PHP Graphviz chromium scaling issue

Tags: php, graphviz

I've been using PHP Graphviz for drawing graphs of my workflow within iframes. Just recently I've started seeing erratic behavior from chromium (on Linux). When I create a simple graph through PHP Graphviz (using the accepted answer here: [PHP GraphViz Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241382/php-graphviz-documentation)), Firefox creates the graph properly and has a scrollbar but chrome scales the whole graph to fit the iframe.

The issue is when the iframe becomes much smaller than the graph, chromium scales the graph down instead of having it scroll thus making the whole thing miniature and unreadable. I can't find any setting for the iframe or PHP Graphviz which will solve the issue.

My iframe document is this:

```
  echo "<iframe id='graphwin' src='/tools/tool-temp-svg2.html' scrollbars='yes' frameborder='1' height='50' width='50'></iframe>";
```

And the inner document is the same as that given in the question linked to above.

The output on chrome looks like this (in real scale):

[image]

Chromium version is: 18.0.1025.151 (Ubuntu 12.04) but is being seen in chrome as well. Firefox works fine.

I've seen bug reports of this kind of behavior on chromium site but they are old and all marked as resolved.

**UPDATE:** Added a demo page here: http://www.legalinfo-online.com/demo/tool-temp-svg.php

Comment: You should offer an URL to reproduce what you talk about, because w/o that it's sort of a guessing game.

Comment: I'm afraid the online url is behind htaccess and I'm not able to provide the link. The problem is reproducible by creating two files. The first file has one line I've pasted above and the second has the code I've linked to. Hope someone would be able to reproduce the error using these two.

Comment: Then do a second setup that is publicly available. Do you really expect that others do that for you?

Comment: @hakre: My apologies for posting such a dumb response. I've added a publicly available demo. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, I have to assume that you're calling the gv->image( ) method without specifying any parameters in which case, gv answers with SVG output.  If this is the case, I think Chromium is doing the right thing, actually.  The iframe gives the bounding box for the svg layout and it just renders the svg to fit within it.

To force the svg to render to a larger size, I think you can alter the viewbox attribute of the svg node to specify the extent of the layout.  The idea being that chromium would render the svg to fit the specified viewbox, then iframe would embed the larger viewbox.  WARNING - I haven't tried this.

Alternatively, as a work-around, you can invoke the gv->image( ) method with parameters to force Graphviz to produce a .png, etc.  As the .png file would have it's own size associated to it, I believe that the embedded iframe would adjust it's internal bounds to fit the .png and then display scrollbars if the internal view is larger than the bounds of the iframe.

Comment: Thanks @parselmouth. Unfortunately, PNG isn't an option since I have to have SVG (which include clickable nodes etc.)

Comment: @recluze  ahhhh...yeah, SVG is nice for that feature.  You should be able to read the SVG DOM, right?  If so, try changing the viewbox attribute - hopefully that will force chromium to render to the specified size rather than the size of the iframe.  Anyway - best wishes for you and your project.