# PEAR Graphviz: Generating Images

Tags: php, graphviz

Having installed the PEAR GraphViz package I'm trying to follow the second answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241382/php-graphviz-documentation) to create a JPEG of a graph. As test code, I have the following:

```
<?php

  require_once 'Image/GraphViz.php';
  $graph = new Image_GraphViz();
  $graph->addNode('A');
  $img = $graph->fetch('jpeg', 'dot');
  print "IMG: " . $img;
```

I've also tried it using the `$graph->image('jpeg', 'dot');` method. Both ways, it returns an empty string. When I change the format to something like SVG, it works, which makes me think that certain image generation libraries just aren't installed. But I have the regular (commandline) Graphviz tools installed and they generate images fine. What do I need to install to make this work so PHP can generate images itself?

Comment: can you try header("Content-type: image/png");
ob_clean();
flush(); after print ? to see if some libraries are missing?

Comment: Got an error because ob had never been started, so I added ob_statr() before print $img (removed the `"IMG: " .` part). Running it in the console prints nothing, looks like the variable is empty like always. Trying to open it in a browser says it couldn't be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: It says here This package is not maintained, if you would like to take over please go to this page. I see last release was in 2010. That was three years ago. Probably there is major differences in php from three years an now. If you need graphs generator why don't you try http://phpmygraph.abisvmm.nl/?

Comment: It's a little late in the process for that, but thanks anyway. We can probably get by with just the HTML that Graphviz is generating, but the images would have been nice to have.